# Why does my dash/hyphen character disappear after onkeup javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace space characters with dashes/hyphens in JavaScript. I got most of the code working so that it adds dashes after each space in between characters (I don't want 2 dashes/hyphen consecutively), but as soon as I hit another character, the dash disappears. Maybe my code isn't formatted correctly?

I'm trying to create something similar like Linkedin when you create a company page it asks you to create a company URL. When you hit a space, it replaces it with dashes/hyphens.

```js
function addHyphen(element) {

  let ele = document.getElementById(element.id);
  ele = ele.value.split('-').join(''); // Remove dash (-) if mistakenly entered.

  let finalVal = ele.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  document.getElementById(element.id).value = finalVal;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = finalVal;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Add Hyphen to a text using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="tbNum" onkeyup="addHyphen(this)" placeholder="Type some values here" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label id="result"></label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On the line where you commented `// Remove dash`, you... remove all dashes

Comment: I know that line was trouble. How do I make sure there aren't 2 consecutives dashes/hyphens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const $result = document.getElementById("result");

function addHyphen($el) {
  $el.value = hyphenize($el.value);
  $result.innerHTML = $el.value;
}

function hyphenize(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '-') // Replace non-alphanumerical chars with '-'
    .replace(/-+/g, '-'); // Deduplicate them
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="tbNum" onkeyup="addHyphen(this)" placeholder="Type some values here" /></div>
<div><label id="result"></label></div>
```